# Intuition about conjugate priors and parameter estimation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, intuition, parameter-estimation

I have a problem that I am starting to work in a field where I need lots of non-rigorous probability theory for modelling.One large stumbling block for me is concept of conjugate Priors of random variables and Parameter estimation.Wherever I look the concepts are explained blurilly,with complete disregard for any kind of mathematical rigor.

I would like an explanation of conjugate priors and parameter estimation techniques, but such that rigor is not disregarded and all steps are laid out so that a complete novice can follow.

Mathematical rigor is wanted,but measure-theoretic arguments are not really welcome since I had no chance to acquainte myself with the theory at all.

Resource recomandations are more then welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where have you looked so far for an explanation? Bishop's book Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning has a pretty decent explanation of conjugate priors. The book Doing Bayesian Data Analysis has a good explanation. The nice thing about a conjugate prior is that the posterior distribution has the same form as the prior distribution, so repeated Bayesian updates can be performed easily.

Comment: The whole "bayesian updating" is Kind of a confusion for me. It seems like all they are doing is following : Given a stohastic process Z(t) obtain a recursion formula for Z(t+1) a set some Z(0) ,but I am most likely wrong.I looked nowhere in particular since the books are either to advanced for me ( Knill Probability Theory , and I hate Jaynes Book ) or they are non-rigorous and at total novice Level ( Sheldon Ross Introduction to Probability Theory ). Currently I am exploring stats stackexchange for answers